# How to change price decimal symbol , in Magento 2 complete store

Tags: magento2, multistore, currency, multicurrency

I created two stores - one for `en_US` other is Arabic that is `ar_KW` for Kuwait

When i switched the store from English to Arabic, my price decimal symbol changed from **"." to ","**. But, in my `en_US` store it shows **"."** only. How to fix this issue ?

**Note :-** In `vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Format.php` I changed **.** to some other symbol but it reflected only in Product Detail page and order summery block. In rest of them, the price symbol is  still **,**. How to fix this issue in one change ?

Answer (score 1):

In vendor`\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\ar.xml` change :

```
<symbols numberSystem="arab">
    <decimal>,</decimal>
```

to

```
<symbols numberSystem="arab">
    <decimal>.</decimal>
```

In php ode level it happens in vendor `\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data.php` in `getList()` method.

you can see switch statement there and you can do the changes in `case 'symbols':`

But, make sure cache is cleared before testing (in local system some times cache will lead to the changes not getting reflected properly)

Comment: Is there anyway to override and not change directly the \magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\xx.xml ?

Comment: Did you get any solution to overide this file the directly than editing in core file

Answer (score 1):

In your /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ path in ar_KW.xml file make chages as below:
add below code in your locale's xml file :

```
<ldml>
...........
<numbers>
    <symbols numberSystem="latn">
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>
        <list>;</list>
        <percentSign>%</percentSign>
        <plusSign>+</plusSign>
        <minusSign>-</minusSign>
        <exponential>E</exponential>
        <superscriptingExponent>×</superscriptingExponent>
        <perMille>‰</perMille>
        <infinity>∞</infinity>
        <nan>NaN</nan>
    </symbols>
</numbers>
.................
</ldml>
```

Run command :
php bin/magento cache:flush