# dot change automatically for comma into item description

Tags: magento2, product, price, catalog-price-rules

Help to solve this bug or problem, into description item, the price change automatically

Ex: my price is: `$1,999.99`

But after few seconds, the price convert comma for dot and dot for a comma:

Ex: my price change for `$1.999,99`

I don't know where is the problem, I tried to find an answer but i can't find it.

Helpme.

Comment: First of all try to change ur Locale & Check. Still Issue
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85100/how-to-convert-number-into-currency-format-in-magento2
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98454/how-to-change-price-decimal-symbol-in-magento-2-complete-store